# How do I ask questions to sentence with few subjects parts of speech?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

Example sentence:

> I worked hard yesterday but she didn't work at all.

Where could I place another sentence in a question when I'm asking to a part of speech of another one?

Is this question to first subject correct?

> Who did work hard yesterday when she didn't work at all?

Comment: Why do you need to ask this question? For a story or some other task? Also, can you explain a bit more what do you want to ask?

Comment: English questions learning.

Comment: The first sentence "I worked yesterday..." is fine, but the question "Who did work hard yesterday when she didn't work at all?" is not, because if she didn't work, then you can't say "when." The question does not appear to be meaningful.

Comment: What could I use to replace 'but' and connect second sentence to the first in the question?

Comment: Maybe this: "Who did work hard yesterday _while_ she didn't work at all?" But I'm not sure if this really works. I would write: "Who did work hard yesterday instead of her who didn't work at all?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may say: "Who did work hard yesterday *while* she didn't work at all?"

*While* connects two events that happened at the same time (both events are in past simple tense).

*When* connects an ongoing action in the past and an event at exact moment in the past that has interrupted the ongoing action. So, this does not work in your example, but works in this example:

"Who was working hard yesterday when she stopped working?" Here "was working" is in [past continuous](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) and "she stopped working" in past tense.